# Twilio Unexpected Hangup causing stuck executions

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I've been developing with Twilio for the last few months and have found that sometimes if a user hangs up during certain studio flow widgets the executions become stuck. This wasn't really a problem until yesterday when we were getting billed for `Gather` widgets after the hangup occurred, as it wasn't leaving the `Gather` widget.

Here's what we've been doing:

... -> Start stream -> Gather verb -> End stream -> ...

So the hangups are happening between the start and end of the streaming.

This happens with a few widgets - here's an example with the SIDs removed for clarity:

`Received an 'hangup' event while processing the 'startStream' widget for Execution Sid foo and Flow Sid bar. Ignoring this event and not transitioning to another widget`

I've noticed this also happens with the `endStream` widget, so I think it's just happening with the streaming.

This happens a lot and results in stuck executions, which I can't ignore due to the way my backend system works.

Does anyone know how to end these stuck executions, or make sure that we don't end up stuck on the widget after a hangup so that they can end more gracefully?

Let me know if there's any more information you need.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so do you mind explaining how you solved the problem? I am dealing with this issue on the gather widget

Comment: Hi @andrewoodleyjr, unfortunately, we didn't get a fix and I'm no longer working on this project so not sure how to help with it - hope you get something sorted and if you do pls leave an answer :) - it seems like an issue on Twilio's side but not sure, maybe worth raising a support ticket if you haven't already?

Comment: Yea, it's something on their end, they are aware and judging on the response they are not motivated to resolve the issue. I will figure something out with a work around.